# Operation not permitted (in target 'path_provider' from project 'Pods')

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods, xcode12, podfile

I'm trying to build a Flutter on iOS but I'm getting this type of error, where I'm told "Operation not permitted in target 'package' from project 'Pods", on few packages.

The packages are:

path_provider-1.6.28

flutter_local_notifications-4.0.1+2

open_file-3.0.3

I've tried to delete the project and clone it again and run `pod install` but it did not work. I also already have a read & write privileges on the app's project folder.

I cannot force any update on my packages as they would contain breaking changes to my code.

Does anyone have an idea of how to resolve this?

Comment: Try to use xcworkspace file for running the app after POD install.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got this to work after giving Xcode full disk access through *System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Privacy -> Full Disk Access* and marked Xcode.